# searching in list of values in dynamodb schema using dynamoose in node

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamoose

I have a dynamo db schema lets say goes like this

```
const team = new dynamoose.Schema(
  {
   bitbucketDetails: [
      {
        id: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        repository: {
          type: String,
        },
      
      },
    ],
})
```

I wanted to search for an item having lets say particular repository "abc". how can i search that?

so far i tried something like
team.scan({ bitbucketDetails: { contains:"abc" }}).all().exec()
but keep saying  **ValidationException: One or more parameter values were invalid: ComparisonOperator CONTAINS is not valid for M AttributeValue type.**

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the value in bitbucketDetails, but you want to look in bitbucketDetails.repository.

Comment: So are you suggesting  team.scan({ bitbucketDetails.repository: { contains:"abc" }}).all().exec().  will work?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Dynamoose, so not sure about semantics. But the idea of your search is wrong. You tried to look over keys in bitbucketDetails, which is a map. Something like that might work team.scan({ bitbucketDetails: {repository: { contains:"abc" }}}).all().exec(). But like I said, not sure if that's the way to build dynamoose conditions